# Exclude dot(.) from extjs number field

Tags: regex, extjs

I have one extjs number field. I can enter numbers 0-9 and dot(.) in it. How can I avoid this dot also. I need only integers. Plase give me the required regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is actually a config property on a `numberfield` to do that, so you can just specify the field like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    allowDecimals: false
}
```

Comment: I was just supplying regex, I have no idea what extjs is - I would hazard that this answer is quite a bit better if there's a built-in option for it!

Comment: @Consciousness this setting will also prevent the user from being able to type a dot into the field (Just FYI ;) ). @dougajmcdonald Your answer would be absolutely perfect if you add a link to the `allowDecimals` API ;) Anyway +1

Answer (score 2):

`/^\d+$/` is the regex you requested.

If you need to capture it, try `/^(\d+)$/`